# House numbers on roads layer

Tags: openstreetmap, layers, streets, numbering

I have a problem regarding the street numbers in OpenStreetMap. I have downloaded the .osm file of a city from the OpenStreetMap web. Then with QGIS I have obtained a shapefile with roads and a shapefile with the buildings.

What I want is to get in one file roads with street numbers and their position. Is there any way to get this?

I have only achieved to get one layer with the roads and one layer with the polygons, where the House numbers are, but I can't find a relation between both layers; also,the street names on the polygons layer are not correct always.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Python to move the points onto the road. You can then do a Spatial Join and attach the info if you require.

```
import arcpy

streets = []

# Geodatabase workspace, use either relative or absolute path
# Currently using relative path because script is in same folder as .gdb
arcpy.env.workspace = r".\TestDataset.gdb"

# Feature Classes
roads = "[YOUR_ROAD_DATA]"
points = "[YOUR_ADDRESS_DATA]"

# Get unique street names from road layer and assign to var 'street'
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(roads, "[YOUR_STREET_NAME_FIELD]") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:        
        if row[0] is not None and row != "":
            if row[0] not in streets:
                streets.append(str(row[0]))

print "Found streets:"
for street in streets:
    print street,

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(roads, "roads_lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points, "points_lyr")

for street in streets:
    try:

        print "\n" + street

        exp_roads = "[YOUR_STREET_NAME_FIELD] = '{0}'".format(street)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("roads_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", exp_roads)


    exp_points = "[YOUR_STREET_NAME_FIELD] LIKE '{0}%'".format(street)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("points_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", exp_points)

    # This tool modifies input data and does not create new data
    # Requires Standard or Advanced License
    arcpy.Snap_edit("points_lyr", [["roads_lyr", "EDGE", "50 Meters"]])
    print "...snapped"

        except:

        print "Error with street: " + street


print "\ndone"
```